# mvc partial view can not be found

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I came across very similar situations on Stackoverflow but so far none of the recommended ways helped me.

A button is supposed to trigger rendering partial view like this

```
<script>
                function forward(element) {
                    var form = $(element).closest('form');
                    form.attr('action', "@Url.Action("ForwardList")");
                    form.attr('data-ajax-method', "POST");
                    form.attr('data-ajax-update', "#ajax-target");
                    form.submit();
                }


            </script>
            <div class="widget-body">
                <div class="mail-header" style="margin-left:0px;">
                    <ul class="header-buttons">
                        //other buttons to the left and right

                        <li>
                            <a class="tooltip-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Forward" onclick="forward(this);"><i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

and the ForwardList Action Result inside FolderController

```
public ActionResult ForwardList(FormCollection coll)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            int CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(identity.FindFirst("CompanyId").Value);
            string SelectedIds = coll["chkGrid"];

            DataSet ds = CompanyDB.Company_List(CompanyId);
            if (DBHelper.DataSetValid(ds, false))
            {
                ViewBag.SelectedIds = SelectedIds;
                return PartialView("~/Views/Folder/_Forward.cshtml", ds.Tables[0]);
            }
            else
                return PartialView();
        }
```

When I debug, it enters the ActionResult and goes all the way then returns 500 error.

Error from `this.Context.AllErrors`returns like this

{"The partial view '~/Views/Folder/_Forward.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:\r\n~/Views/Folder/_Forward.cshtml"}

partial view is set to be built as Content.

Structure is like this
Areas/
  Main/
   Views/
     Folder/
       _Forward.cshtml.

Only possibility I haven't ruled out is that it's about Ajax form but I'm not experienced enough in Ajax to know if it's about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include area in your partial view

```
return PartialView("~/Areas/yourArea/Views/Folder/_Forward.cshtml", ds.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's always the smallest overlooked details that frustrate most  :)